# Possible bug in reputation calculation/voting

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, voting

I had an old question get closed recently and noticed in my reputation display that I got back +2 for a "undownvote" a couple of days later. It seems odd that a person would or could remove a down vote only days after the question was closed after such a length of time. <strike>I didn't notice any other edits or votes recently on that question.</strike> The downvote apparently occurred on the same day it was closed.

Does closure count as an edit that would allow someone to change a vote cast long ago? If so, is that intended? Did the recent (and perhaps ongoing) changes to the reputation calculation code somehow forgive the down vote as a result of the recent closure? That seems to be an error.

Here's a link to the question: [Getting back on track after disruptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382200/getting-back-on-track-after-disruptions)

Note: the question hasn't been deleted, just closed, though I expect it soon will be now that I've posted a link to it on meta.  I don't know if it would be helpful to the team to wait until they've had a chance to investigate the issue, but on the outside chance that it would be, could you please wait until this is resolved before casting your delete vote?

**Edit**: I should also add that the reason I noticed this is because my rep went from ...,908 to ...,875.  I looked to see why and saw another question on which I had an accepted, 2 x upvoted answer had been deleted.  This should have been a -35 drop, but it showed up as a -33 drop.  That's what made me start looking for the discrepancy.  According to the timeline the "undownvote" happened 11 hours ago so I have no idea why it just showed up, either.

Comment: If the user who down-voted you was deleted/destroyed then their votes would disappear. So if they had down-voted you it would be an "undownvote" when the votes were invalidated.

Comment: @ChrisF really? I assumed all their activity got converted into some "anonymous" user.

Comment: Ah, yes you're right - I was confusing things. However there are cases  where votes are removed and in the case of vote fraud and when serial down-voting is detected it has to invalidate *all* votes.

Comment: @ChrisF see my update on why it seemed really odd to me.

Comment: The vote is removed as part of a daily job...though I'm honestly not sure if it's intentional, not touching the job until someone can answer that, Sam should be back monday to take a look.

Comment: @NickCraver any clues on why the rep restore didn't show up until after the other question was removed even though it apparently happened 11 hours earlier?  Maybe the daily job doesn't trigger the recalculation code?

Comment: @NickCraver - my rep just went up by 2 without any corresponding "undownvote" in my reputation display.  In fact, no activity in the last 45 minutes or so.  Weird.

Comment: @NickCraver - can you verify that I am able to see all "deleted" reputation on my account.  I started out today around ...,908 and am ending up at ...,882 but show a net gain of 82 on the day.  I'm seriously confused.  I see some deleted activity, but not enough to account for that.

Comment: @tvanfosson - those community votes were not being recorded properly...that'll now happen within 5 minutes of the daily job completing.  I'll make it immediate with a bit of re-working tomorrow.

Comment: @NickCraver I haven't said anything about it because I figured you were working on the code but the same day I posted this, by the end of the day, I had gone from ..3,008 to ..2,686 -- with nothing in any recent day's rep display to show why (yes, the show removed box was/is checked).  That ring any bells?

Comment: @tvanfosson - I believe that's the day we fixed the dupe rep from migrated away answers bug (there was missing history there we had to backfill), affected users were recalced as part of that.  That was the last history-changing rep recalc on the table, everything on my list left is skew caused by a gap in current code not recording/updating correctly as it goes somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, this is weird - the only "down vote" you got on that post was the one from [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) - that wonderful evil bot who goes around kicking people when they're down by down-voting posts closed as Off Topic.

I don't know why Community would ever retract the down-vote unless the post was re-opened. Everyone knows, bots have no concept of mercy.

Comment: *Darren and I have a policy with Old Glory Insurance, in case we're attacked by Community.*