# 10 reputation points gone into Oblivion

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation, reputation-history

On Stack Overflow I'm 100% sure that I had 21,530 reputation couple of days ago (Friday, March 9<sup>th</sup>) and this morning (Sunday March 11<sup>th</sup>) I noticed it's 21,521 - my [reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447356/shadow-wizard?tab=reputation&sort=time) does explain the +1 for removed answer which I downvoted:

[image: reputation history]

However there is nothing about the missing 10 reputation - common sense tells it's a removed question which I answered and got 1 upvote but then it should have been displayed in the reputation history.

Important to mention, the [good old reputation sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) also reach 21,521 rep.

Can anyone please help me find my precious 10 points? :)

Tagging as bug since it's likely a bug in the "removed" display or calculation.

**Edit**: the "show removed posts" checkbox was checked when taking the screenshot - however now after unchecking it and checking it again, even the +1 is gone:

[image: rep history again]

Voodoo?

**Edit 2**: Another weirdness:

[image: another issue]

This links to [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309107/javascript-document-form-submit-not-working/5309259#5309259) that was indeed upvoted on March 16<sup>th</sup> 2011 at 05:16 however both the upvote and the unupvote shows no reputation change and the weird part - that post has no activity whatsoever. Maybe someone upvoted and today his account got nuked?

Comment: [Maybe a migrated answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125121/145673)

Comment: @Martin good call! Posted comment to Rebecca answer, hope to get official response soon.

Comment: Welcome to the rep yo-yo.  I've noticed weird, inexplicable losses to my rep recently as well. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124883/possible-bug-in-reputation-calculation-voting It's happened a couple of times after that as well, both on SO and meta.  It would be nice to get an explanation.  On SO I feel like I've earned the last 2-300 points 3 times over with nothing in the rep display to show it.  I can only surmise that bug fixes are modifying older items in my timeline.

Comment: @tvanfosson yeah, lol.. well - there must be *some* explanation for what's going on - I believe those are "rep monsters" that always lived in darkness and now the new calculation method is bringing them out to the light.

Comment: See @NickCraver's last comment on my referenced question.  Seems like there are a few issues around migrations yet.

Comment: @tvanfosson let's hope so. Will keep an eye over this. :-)

Comment: This is most likely not a bug, just a caching difference...

Comment: @Tom no, the reputation in the profile page is live plus I've reproduced this in the [raw profile sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation).

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: Have you triggered a recalculation? Are you sure there is no caching involved, [because it happens every once in a while](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121741/145350).

Comment: @Tom yes and yes. It got nothing to do with the accounts reputation cache as it happens in the profile reputation tab not the reputation shown in the accounts display. Found yet another issue will post it asap.

Comment: @ShadowWizard cleaning up old posts... Are you still having rep issues in this manner, or is this good to close?

Comment: Thanks @Haney, no further issues so safe to close as no-repro. :)

Comment: I found your 10 rep points!!!!!!! They are there, you just should have looked more attentively.

Comment: @nicael how? can you tell me.

Comment: @VScode_fanboy I am not sure what's your question about :)

Comment: @nicael he's asking how you found the 10 points.

Comment: @Sha I don't think I remember that xd

Comment: @nicael well, when you're [over 100 years old](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=3114460#3114460) it's only natural memory won't be that good... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. After discussing it with Shadow Wizard, I am unable to reproduce the issue at hand. Shadow also confirms that he has not had any further issues, so this is [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro).

Comment: And here are your lost 25 points! :D